# MySQL shared hosting: db is MyISAM, although all created tables are InnoDB. Can I switch? Should I?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, shared-hosting, myisam

My question is about the Type of db that is on a shared hosting Linux server. phpMyAdmin shows that db has MyISAM Type. I don't think I can change it. I mean I don't know. 
All tables in that db have InnoDB type.
Does it make sense to change db type to InnoDB? Should I? (I don't know if I can choose a db type on a shared hosting server).
Of course I can contact a customer support and ask them to switch if they can, but I don't know if it makes any sense and has any pros.

Should I take care of it?

Thank you[image].
Added: The image above is a screenshot from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You should mention that you screen shot is from phpmyadmin :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default storage engine of the server. If you do not specify a storage engine when creating a table then the server picks MyISAM as the default

For example on my server InnoDB is the default.

```
mysql> show engines\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Engine: InnoDB
     Support: DEFAULT
     Comment: Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
Transactions: YES
          XA: YES
  Savepoints: YES
```

Also in answer to your second question. Yes you can change the storage engine. You can do this with the ALTER TABLE command.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

I suggest not to change storage engines unless you have a specific need for a feature in an engine.

Comment: Do you recommend to leave the default storage engine that hosting provider suggests even if all db tables are InnoDB? I can recreate the db and all tables from the very beginning as I don't have useful info in it yet. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is fine. Especially if the server is shared. The default engine changed between versions of MySQL. Your provider is not recommending a particular one. Use the storage engine you want (InnoDB is probably best choice general today). You can also change the storage engine with phpmyadmin if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You might misunderstanding, database does not have a [storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html).
The storage engine is meant for table.
You can only switch the storage engine for tables.

However, myisam does not support transactional,
and innodb (mysql version <5.6) does not support full-text search.

Without knowing which tables in which database,
my guess is you should not change the storage engine.

Example :-

http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/index.php?lang=en&collation_connection=utf8_general_ci

The bottom row showing in phpmyadmin is the equivalent of :-

```
show create database YOUR_DATABASE;
```

when you create new table without specify a storage engine,
the default storage engine type on the database will apply to it.

for [mysql version 5.5, default storage engine is change to innodb.](http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2010/09/mysql-5-5-innodb-as-default-storage-engine/)

there is no direct way to change database default storage engine after you have create a database

the workaround is create a new database with you desired default storage engine,
then rename all the tables currently reside in the existing database to this database.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Without knowing which tables in which database"... And why do I see MyISAM in phpMyAdmin right after Total number of tables? What does it mean in this case then? Thank you.

Comment: The screen capture does not show what are the table in which database. The count is simply to allow you to know total count of table group by storage engine

Comment: @ajreal - you are wrong. phpmyadmin is showing the default storage engine of the MySQL server. Mouse over the field and find the popup help.

Comment: @Adrian Mind to show me a link? (The screen capture does not look like a mouse over thing)

Comment: @ajreal - I cant find one - best I can do is the html from my phpmyadmin install <dfn title="InnoDB is the default storage engine on this MySQL server.">InnoDB</dfn>

Comment: is the same as `show create database YOUR_DATABASE;`, Yes, is not really a count of table.